# Compute angle between two objects in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, angle

I have some specific images of two objects (a phone and a TV remote) and I want to calculate the angle between two edges that intersect of these. I used Canny to detect the edges and Hough line for the angle, but the hough_line() function found too many angles that doesnt match the requirement.
Original image:

[image]

This is the requirement:

[image: Requirement]

And this is which I made:  [image: Result]
My code:

```
import cv2
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


def edge_detection(img, blur_ksize=5, threshold1=100, threshold2=200):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (blur_ksize, blur_ksize), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gaussian, threshold1, threshold2)

    return img_canny


image = edge_detection(cv2.imread('img1.png'))

h, theta, d = hough_line(image)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 6))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].set_title('Input image')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

ax[1].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0 = (dist - 0 * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    y1 = (dist - image.shape[1] * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax[1].plot((0, image.shape[1]), (y0, y1), '-r')
ax[1].set_xlim((0, image.shape[1]))
ax[1].set_ylim((image.shape[0], 0))
ax[1].set_axis_off()
ax[1].set_title('Detected lines')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

angle = []
dist = []
for _, a , d in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    angle.append(a)
    dist.append(d)

angle = [a*180/np.pi for a in angle]
print(angle)
```

Are there any ways to detect and calculate exactly one angle I need in opencv? Thanks a lot

**Update**
I tried different values of `blur_ksize`, `threshold1` and `threshold2` in Canny detection, it's seem like I could remove redundant lines, but now the angles those hough_line_peaks() return are negative. Can anyone explain this for me? And I also want to put the angle values to the peaks in plot, to see which angle has which value
[image]

Comment: As long as the lines are parallel, they should have the same angle between them. Can you try eliminating the redundant lines by seeing which one of them passes through the remote's body (just an idea)?

Comment: Are you able to detect/segment the objects?

Comment: the hough transform found some lines that aren't there. address that (fiddle with parameters). don't worry about lines "passing through" objects. you'd have to locate objects for that, which is a bigger task than finding lines. if you had the objects separated from the background, the rest of your task would be easier though.

Comment: Please, share the original (not annotated) image.

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample solution, but I don't know whether it works for all images. You have to tune the hough transform parameters.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def edge_detection(img, blur_ksize=5, threshold1=70, threshold2=200):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (blur_ksize, blur_ksize), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gaussian, threshold1, threshold2)

    return img_canny

img = cv2.imread('stack.png')
image = edge_detection(img)

minLineLength = 300
maxLineGap = 80
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image,1,np.pi/180,50,minLineLength,maxLineGap)

equations = []
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    equations.append(np.cross([x1,y1,1],[x2,y2,1]))
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),2)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
thetas = []
N = len(equations)
for ii in range(1,N):
    a1,b1,c1 = equations[0]
    a2,b2,c2 = equations[ii]
    # intersection point
    pt = np.cross([a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2])
    pt = np.int16(pt/pt[-1])
    # angle between two lines
    num = a1*b2 - b1*a2
    den = a1*a2 + b1*b2
    if den != 0:
        theta = abs(np.arctan(num/den))*180/3.1416
        # show angle and intersection point
        cv2.circle(img, (pt[0],pt[1]), 5, (255,0,0), -1)
        cv2.putText(img, str(round(theta, 1)), (pt[0]-20,pt[1]-20), font, 0.8, (255,0,0), 2, 0)
        thetas.append(theta)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Angle between two lines]

Comment: How you got that for of calculating the intersection? it is very clever, i checked how it works on [geogebra snippet](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/eppn8wkc)